# Javascript string replace: Can we use a string as the first argument (for speed) but "match globally"?

Tags: javascript, string

`string.replace(/\./g,'_')` is the behavior I'd like, but I'd rather not use an actual regex due to [this jsperf](http://jsperf.com/replace-vs-split-join-vs-replaceall/24) which shows that using a string e.g. `string.replace('.','_')` is much faster.

Unfortunately (and this might be kind of damning for jsperf, as this is not made obvious in any way) it looks like the replace will only work on the first match, so it's identical only to

```
string.replace(/\./,'_')
```

That is perhaps enough to invalidate the comparison because it's only really twice as fast (on Webkit) for the plain-string `replace`, but it's actually only doing 1/4 of the work by replacing only one period with a space rather than all of them.

There's an obvious approach which is

```
while(string.indexOf('.') !== -1) string = string.replace('.','_');
```

but is there perhaps an even better or faster way to achieve this?

Comment: Not sure about better or faster but there's another approach `'this is string'.split('.').join('_');` and not to be a stickler but the while loop is going to be an infinite one :D

Comment: Try it out on the jsperf and see. It isn't that hard to do, isn't it?

Comment: @Ejay `join`&`split` works too but if the JS engine does not do anything smart, it's going to allocate an array consisting of separate strings which add up the length of the original string (minus the number of delimiters). this has to got to be even less efficient (particularly for memory) than a regex. and thanks for tip about inf. loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, [the performance test speaks for itself](http://jsperf.com/replace-vs-split-join-vs-replaceall/26#run). *I have modified the last test* to do a "replace loop" (don't mind the prototype attachment, it's just a test)

```
String.prototype.loopReplace = function(replacee,replacer){
  var result = this;
  while(!!~(result = result.replace('.',' ')).indexOf('.')){}
  return result;
}
```

And among the browsers tested, the pre-created RegExp wins over the others and for good reason:

- Since the RegExp is always the same, caching it is a good idea rather than recreating the same objects on the spot.
- The `indexOf`-`replace` loop is slow probably because of the repetetive `indexOf` and `replace` operations. `replace` *creates a new string every time it is run*, which could possibly be the cause.
- `split`-`join` is slow probably because the browser has to create an array first, then a string, and discard the array afterwards. Though browsers may have optimized array creation, it's still slower.

Comment: Cases 2 & 3 aren't correct. They will replace all the characters. It should be `new RegExp("\\.","gm");`

Comment: @MattBurland currently testing, after I saw all comments. Updating in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

Wait a minute. This:

```
string.replace( /./g, '_' )
```

is not the same as this:

```
string.replace( '.', '_' )
```

The first one replaces *any* character with underscore, not just periods.

Don't you mean:

```
string.replace( /\./g, '_' )
```

See how that does for performance; it may be better than the incorrect one.

Also, are you doing a lot of these in a row? Does performance even matter?

Comment: In the perf the OP posted, they did correctly escape the `.`, however their "dynamic" regex case is wrong and does actually replace all the characters with spaces.

Comment: Ah yes. sorry. hastily written question

Answer (score 0):

Your jsperf isn't a fair comparison since the `string.replace('.','_')` isn't actually doing the same job. Comparing code that replaces 1 `.` with code that replaces 4 `.`s isn't particularly useful. [Here's](http://jsperf.com/replace-vs-split-join-vs-replaceall/28)  a fairer comparison (and giving the non-regex replace the best chance by unrolling the loop) where you see the using a regex is actually faster.

Comment: The dynamic regex `new RegExp(".","gm");` is wrong. The dot should be escaped.

Comment: @plalx: Yeah, I just noticed that too after Michael's comment.

Comment: Yeah the jsperf I lifted from somewhere else and did not do much maintenance on it.